# Free alternative to TFS work item

Tags: c#, tfs, continuous-integration, bug-tracking

I'm looking for a free way to automate builds and manage work items (including bug-tracking) for a small open-source team (mostly myself and 1 to 3 other developers). I checked many products and for now, the best I could found was TeamCity but this tool doesn't seem to have work item management (tasks, bugs, requirements etc).

I use SVN as my source control, VS2008 as my IDE and if possible, my build manager / work item management software would run on IIS 6.0 but I've no trouble installing Apache if there's no way to avoid it.

Is TeamCity the better solution (maybe with some add-ons for work item management) or if another stack of products could be a better choice.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). The best there is (IMHO). Visit [trac-hacks.org](http://trac-hacks.org) to get some add-ons. It integrates with SVN nicely, so you can close tickets just by writing appropriate commit messages.

-- Edit

I note the first part of your post mentions 'automating builds'. For this purpose, unless you already have, get yourself a CI server: [CruiseControl.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/) is the typical one, you may also try [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I took a look at trac but I would prefer a .Net product running on IIS if possible. Is there other alternative to trac ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try Hudson as my CI and propably give a try to JIRA which is free for open source projects and integrate with svn and Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

You can now get [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) with a 10 user license for just $10 on Atlassian's [starter license deal](http://www.atlassian.com/starter/).  JIRA has issue tracking, project management, customisable workflow, and extensions for integrating with SVN.

For continuous integration, you can't go far wrong with either TeamCity of CruiseControl.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I was a long-time TFS fan boy. I loved that it was integrated with TFS Version Control (which was a huge improvement over Visual Source Safe) and that it had an automated build process.

I personally am now a huge fan of Redmine.  It is fairly flexible and it is blistering fast. I was able to use Redmine over a 128kb connection without any problems. The thing I like most about Redmine is that it is very simple and unintrusive in the development process.  It will integrate with just about any version control software (I use it with git), and it parses the commits and automatically links the commits back to the work items.

It is a ruby on rails project, which was not ideal for me, being a C# fan, but I found it very easy to install and there are number of great plugins.

I currently am running:

- Redmine for issue management, project planning and time keeping
- Gitlab for Version control
- Jenkins for automated builds and CI